# JavaScript - function as an object property

Tags: javascript

Hey everyone, this is  #23 from John Resig Advanced JavaScript http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#23, called

> `What happens if a function is an
>   object property.`

1) regarding vocabulary,  the variable katana is the object, right? If the anonymous function is its property, then what is "use" called? I thought "use" would have also been called a property? or is "use" also an object because it contains a value, namely a function?

2). Is the purpose of the function to change isSharp: true to isSharp: false?  What does !this.isSharp exactly do?

3) When it asserts !katana.isSharp, what is it actually asserting? that isSharp has now been set to  "false"?

```
var katana = {
  isSharp: true,
  use: function(){
    this.isSharp = !this.isSharp;
  }
};
katana.use();
assert( !katana.isSharp, "Verify the value of isSharp has been changed." );
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1. Yes, `katana` is an object (created using the `{ ... }` notation). "use" is the name of the property of the object whose *value* will be the anonymous function (which is also an object).
2. The function inverts the value of `isSharp` (so from `true` to `false` or `false` to `true`).
3. It is asserting that `isSharp` is something which does not evaluate to true (this is nearly everything except `undefined`, `null`, `false`, `0`, etc). In this case, since `isSharp` is always either `true` or `false`, it is asserting that it is `false`.

The main point (and cool part) of the sample is this line:

```
katana.use();
```

This first fetches the value of the "use" property from the `katana` object (that's the `katana.use` part). The value is the anonymous function from before. Then, that function is executed (that's the `()` part). The really cool part is that it is executed *on behalf of the `katana` object* -- that means `this` in the anonymous function is a reference to the `katana` object when it's called that way.

Comment: it's asserting isSharp is "falsy"! falsy and not true are (distinctly) different.

Comment: @Raynos: Heh, yeah, that's why I put "not true" instead of "not `true`". It makes sense if you define true as "something which is not false" :-) I'll make it less ambiguous, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: thank you very much. You say the cool part is that it is executed on behalf of the Katana object. Why is it cool? Does the create some practical advantage? If so, what is the practical advantage it gives?

Comment: @mjmitche: I just think it's cool (it's very subjective) that an anonymous function which is not attached to any particular object can be executed on behalf of one without needing to call `apply`. (Admittedly, most of Javascript OOP is done this way, but I still marvel at it.) There's no *practical* advantage, just some nice syntactic sugar which also makes it "just work" in most cases even if you don't realize what's going on

Answer (score 1):

1) `Katana` is an object. `Katana.use` is a function. Its a property that contains a function as value. The value it contains happens to be an anonymous function.

The distinction is that `Katana.use` is a property of `Katana` and that the value of `Katana.use` is a function. `use` is a key defined on `Katana` since `Katana["use"]` also works.

2) It's setting isSharp to NOT isSharp so either true -> false or false -> true

3) the assert is saying `katana.isSharp === false` which it should be since it was orginally true but then set to false.

Answer (score 1):

1. `use` is a property of the object `katana`.
2. !this.isSharp will negate the value of this.isSharp. Ex if isSharp is true it will return false else it return false.
3. The assert checks whether the result of the boolean result is true. If the result is false then the assertion fails.