# Why Javascript import function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, scope

i want to understand a little bit more about the javascript reference scope, i was trying to import a function from onother file like this

**file1.js**

```js
exports.checkIfCan = function(){
 //make some check
}

exports.calculate = function(){
   this.checkIfCan();
}
```

and using the calculate method with this import

**file2.js**

```js
const { calculate } = require('./file1.js')

calculate()
```

actually the error is `this.checkIfCan is not a function`
but if i import all the module  like this it works

```
const calculation = require('./file1.js')

calculation.calculate();
```

I just wanna understand more about the global/local scope in javascript

Comment: You need to check classes instead. You want to create an object with functions on it. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334383/javascript-function-as-an-object-property

Comment: I'm not getting any error and both of your cases are working in my case....lol

Comment: Is `exports.calculate = () => {` definitely using an arrow function, and isn't `exports.calculate = function() {`. Your error seems to suggest that you're not using arrow functions

Comment: @NickParsons you're right, i'm not using arrow function, but why it should work with?

Comment: @VladVlads the this keyword works slightly differently in arrow functions than it does within regular functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` refers to the context of the function invocation, which in your case is `undefined` (on browsers the default is `window`).

Here's an example as simple as possible to make you understand it:

```js
calculation.calculate(); // <= you are calling calculate from calculation, so 'this' is calculation

calculate(); // <= you are calling calculate from... nothing, so 'this' is undefined
```

Update: using arrow functions it would work either case because `this` will be taken from the function's surrounding scope instead of the context, and in the top-level code in a Node module `this` is equivalent to `module.exports`.

There's a lot to explain about the `this`in javascript, may I suggest you read the free ebook [You Don't Know JS: this and Object prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/README.md#you-dont-know-js-this--object-prototypes)? You'll find much more information there.

Comment: This would be the case if OP was using regular functions, but since OP is using arrow functions the `this` will be taken from the surrounding scope and not based on how the function is called.

Comment: @NickParsons What a fail! You're right, I didn't even read it correctly. I'll either improve my answer or remove it, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: no worries. But it looks like OP has updated their answer, so your answer is good now 

Comment: That's great, but still I've added some indication about arrow functions and node. Hope it's comprehensible 

Answer (score 0):

@Vlad Vlads, your problem is in the use of keyword **this** in your file file **file1.js**.

In accordance to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this, following behaviour may happen:

> The value of **this** is determined by **how** a **function** is
> **called** **(runtime binding)**. It can't be set by assignment during
> execution, and **it may be different each time** the **function** is **called**.

With that been said, if you remove the keyword **this** in your function, following will then works as expected:

```
const { calculate } = require('./file1.js')

calculate()
```

Your second example will also works as expected

```
const calculation = require('./file1.js')

calculation.calculate()
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use import instead:

file1.js

```
function abc() {}

export {
   abc
}
```

file2.js

```
import { abc } from 'file1.js';
abc();
```

Comment: `import` is ES6 module syntax,  which OP isn't using here. `require()` and `module.exports` is fine for CommonJS modules, which is what OP appears to be using here.

Comment: maybe he's using, you don't know. if he happen to use it in node.js like he tagged or frameworks like React, Vue, or Angular, then using import is supported and it is where the future is heading. You can't just downvote like this.

Comment: The exports object does not exist in ES6 modules, so if the OP was using that then they’d be getting other errors. For what it’s worth the down vote isn’t mine